# Combining gradients

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So I was able to create two gradients based out of the 1x2 operator on an image, my problem is that I can't seem to combine them into one:

```
for i=1:ROWS-1
    for j=1:COLS-1
    Work = double(I1(i,j:j+1)).*Kern;   
    Omegav(i,j) = sum(Work(:));
    end
end

Kernh= [-1;1];
Omegah = zeros([size(I1,1) size(I1,2)]);
for i=1:ROWS-1
    for j=1:COLS-1
    Workh = double(I1(i:i+1,j)).*Kernh;  
    Omegah(i,j) = sum(Workh(:));
    end
    end
```

So these are the two gradients. I had originally put in a Combined empty array like: Combined(i,j,1)= sum(workH(:)); right in between the horizontal and vertical summations but I didn't get any picture there, what could be the reason for that or is there a better way to combine them?

Comment: Currently, you are not asking a matlab question. And it seems you are good with the image processing concepts. Please ask questions using [minimally self-contained examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Argyll wait what? this is the matlab syntax, I can screen shot the code in Matlab if you'd like. and this is as minimal as possible for how I created both gradients. I am stuck in creating one single image combining the points of both gradients. The combined array didn't get populated with the points from both for loops and just shows a blank picture.

Comment: Read the whole description of the requirements: [mcve]. Not only minimal. Also complete, you are even missing an `end`, apart from all the undeclared variables. Also, you are just programming image-kernel convolution, there are hundreds of working MATLAB codes, consider looking at them instead of continuously asking practically the same question over and over again

Comment: While yes, I didn't find one that deals with this kernel, nor did I find one in combining gradients together. I keep finding the conv method which is one I do not want to do, but not of that method. If I had found one I wouldn't have put this question there.

Comment: There are many different ways to combine derivatives. Are you looking for the gradient magnitude maybe? -- or did I get it all wrong and you're looking to combine the two loops into one?

Comment: @Cris Luengo The latter.

Comment: @MarorinQ: my suggestion is to separate any question belonging to image processing from any coding question. In your case, if you are not clear as to how to combine gradients mathematically, you would need to describe an example (using matlab code is fine), what you have understood and ask what you don't understand. If your issue is with implementation, you need to nail down the section of the code that gives problem and re-write that section in your question so that it is context-free. Obviously also share any error message or erroneous result. Follow the article linked for guidelines.

Comment: You may wonder whether you should invest the time to always polish your question. First, if you do, you may be able to answer your own question in the process. Second, if you do, your question will get answered quickly. People are unlikely to waste time on a poorly framed question and since the time required to answer a poor question to satisfactions can be better spent by answering other questions that can help the rest of the community. Last but not least, it takes you effort now. It won't take as much in the future as you learn what works the best. Some things to think about.

Comment: @Argyll I guess I didn't write out the question in the proper way, I'm sorry about that, it was early in the morning and the coffee didn't kick in so to speak when I wrote this out I believe I fixed it by just using imadd on the two gradients. Now while I'm not sure 100 % thats the right way of doing it, I guess I'll chance it and just delete this question?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. If you wish, you could also answer your own question after clarifying it a little. Someone in the future may benefit from what you wrote now. Sometimes a single question/answer helps a lot of people.